# How do I set an animated GIF as my desktop wallpaper?

Tags: macos, wallpaper

How can I make my desktop wallpaper image an animated GIF?

Comment: try this. http://www.furrysoft.de/?page=deskfun

Answer (score 2):

You can use Mojave's dynamic wallpaper. macOS doesn't natively support animated GIFs as wallpapers.

However you can use this https://lifehacker.com/set-an-animated-gif-as-your-macs-wallpaper-1756859302
but at the cost of a shorter battery life for a wallpaper that you probably wouldn't see in action because you got windows all over.

Your case is more like needing a really thin phone(GIF) which you are gonna cover with a case(windows) anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this tool to set animated GIFs on your desktop: [Bionix Animated Desktop Wallpaper](http://www.bionixwallpaper.com/downloads/Animated%20Desktop%20Wallpaper/index.html)

Comment: That is a GREAT and FUN tool but it only works on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7509329

> I'm afraid OS X does not provide for animated wallpaper. There are
>   some apps that claim to do this such as DeskFun and BioniX.

Comment: Does this relate to Mojave or to earlier releases?

Comment: @nohillside As far as I know this will work for Mojave

Answer (score 0):

My best idea is to make the GIF into a bunch of sperate images, put them all in a folder, and then say to change wallpaper every 5 minutes in order.  It's not ideal, but it's probably the best way to do this without installing any third-party software.

Answer (score 0):

As yet another free alternative to run GIFs and APNGs as desktop wallpaper I wrote the screensaver AnimatedGif. It is complete Open Source and can be found on GitHub.

https://github.com/Waitsnake/AnimatedGif/releases/latest/