# Set a screensaver as a background for Desktop?

Tags: desktop, screensaver, wallpaper

I have a really nice Matrix  inspired screensaver. I would like to have the moving screensaver to be placed as my Desktop background image.

How can I set my screensaver as a background image for the desktop ?

Comment: you say it is animated !

Comment: here are some answers http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/60657/46541 and here http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20020824082233907

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open terminal and type `cd /System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources`
and `./ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine -background`. It will take a lot of resources though, so to quit it, you have to quit the terminal window.

source: [TUAW](http://www.tuaw.com/2008/08/25/terminal-tips-make-your-screensaver-a-desktop-background/) and [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/set-a-screen-saver-as-your-macs-desktop-background-1580672554)

Answer (score 1):

You also can create an plist file that you place in your user LaunchAgent folder.

```
/Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents/com.username.runscreensaver.plist
```

You than loaded at a terminal with:

```
launchctl load /Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents/com.username.runscreensaver.plist
```

Or unload it with:

```
launchctl unload /Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents/com.username.runscreensaver.plist
```

Here is the content of this plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<true/>
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.username.runscreensaver</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine</string>
    <string>-background</string>
</array>
<key>ThrottleInterval</key>
<integer>0</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Unfortunately (at least under 10.9.5) the ScreenSaverEngine set the window level wrong (below kCGDesktopWindowLevel) to work correct with mission control and spaces witch leads to a few issues during restart, change screen, login and logout that leads to an invisible screensaver .

To fix this issues you need to write your own screensaver that inherits the properties of ScreenSaverEngine while running and correct the window level (eg. [self.window setLevel:kCGDesktopWindowLevel];).